# vertical center aligned inside align environment

Tags: math-mode, align, boxes

How can I make the top of the aligned pack vertically aligns with the `x ->`?
How can I use a box or something to achieve this? (There are other options of course but I would like to use box or something ...?)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
          f(x) : \quatS \quad &\maps \quad \quatS \\
                        x \quad &\mapsto \quad 
          \begin{aligned}
             &f(x) = \\
             &g \circ h(x) 
          \end{aligned}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\quatS` and `\maps` are not defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Environment has an optional argument for the vertical position, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\providecommand*{\quatS}{QS}% some dummy
\providecommand*{\maps}{\rightarrow}% some dummy
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
          f(x) : \quatS \quad &\maps \quad \quatS \\
                        x \quad &\mapsto \quad
          \begin{aligned}[t]
             &f(x) = \\
             &g \circ h(x)
          \end{aligned}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: ahh, did not found that in the ams manual

Comment: @Gabriel It's mentioned in section 3.7 (first sentence on page 8).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `stackengine` approach.  It seems to get the vertical alignments slightly better than the `aligned` alternative (i.e., the "Q", the "f" and the "g" alignment).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\stackMath
\providecommand*{\quatS}{QS}% some dummy
\providecommand*{\maps}{\rightarrow}% some dummy
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
          f(x) : \quatS \quad &\maps \quad \quatS \\
                        x \quad &\mapsto \quad 
             \def\stackalignment{l}\def\stacktype{L}
             \stackunder{
             f(x) = }{
             g \circ h(x)
          }
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]